# Reinstall Linux Package with File Backup

Tags: linux, apache2, debian, raspberry-pi, apt-get

I installed `apache2` on my `Raspberry Pi`, which runs `Debian OS`.

```
apt-get intall apache2
```

Then I removed it using

```
apt-get remove apache2
```

But its files were present there, and I could also find some other packages related to `apache2` over `dpkg`. So, I manually deleted the `apache2` file from `/etc/`.

Now when I try to install the apache2 back. It installs it, but do not `recalls` all the files that were deleted.

**I am looking for a fresh installation, for the `apache2` with all new fresh files**

What should I do.?

Comment: Try the related StackExchange sites [Server Fault](http://serverfault.stackexchange.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.stackexchange.com/) or [Raspberry Pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
apt-get purge apache2
```

followed by

```
apt-get autoclean
```

and then finally

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Works on ubuntu on my desktop. Not sure about RasPi though.
So, inform me about the results

try to reconfigure the package maybe?

```
dpkg-reconfigure apache2
```

good luck

Answer (score 1):

To completly remove all files and dependency packages try

```
apt-get --purge autoremove apache2
```

After that you can do a fresh install of apache2

```
apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: I need to get back the deleted files from installations. Like in Windows if you manually delete any file from program files, then it would come back after reinstallation. but here this is not working. When I re-install the way you told it would not install the missing files to `/etc/apache2`

Comment: There is no solution if we consider `Raspberry Pi`. You have to pay for your mistake and re-install the complete raspian from starting.

Comment: @Veer are you referring to files you placed there, which are not part of the Debian package?

Comment: Then how should I do that.

Answer (score 1):

try:

sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2.2-common apache2-utils

then:

sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2.2-common apache2-utils

Answer (score 0):

Actually when working on Raspian. you cannot do so.

If you uninstall the package using `apt-get remove` then it is OK.

But that will not remove the files made by the package. So, it will keep the files there. But if in case you delete the files from there then you cannot get it back using `apt-get install`

There must be a way, but I am not aware of that.

So the best and the easiest way is reinstall the complete OS.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same position (manually deleted `/etc/apache2` and couldn't get it to reinstall those files).

I managed to get it to reinstall a fresh copy of Apache2 without reinstalling the whole OS with two commands:

```
apt-get --purge autoremove apache2
apt-get install apache2 --reinstall
```